# iOS blink animation on UIView with finite number of times

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4, xcode9.4

I am trying to create a blinking effect on the UIView. Currently I am using a code which blinks the UIView with infinite number of times. the Code looks like this

**WhatI have done so far:**

```
 func startBlink() {
                  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8,//Time duration
                                delay:0.0,
                                options:[.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
                                animations: { self.alpha = 0 },
                                completion: nil)
        }
```

But this code blinks the ui view for infinite number of time. I used another code but that was blinking for one time only.

**What I want:**

> So I am pretty close but I really want to blink the UIView for finite
>   number of times i.e 30 times, and it must stop after 30th blink.

Please help me in this, I think I have clear in my question. Please help me out.

Comment: Consider using timer. Count the number of times it fired, then invalidate timer.

Comment: Are you implement the function inside UIView's extension ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this function to animate View. I hope it can help

```
extension UIView {  
        func flash(numberOfFlashes: Float) {
           let flash = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
           flash.duration = 0.2
           flash.fromValue = 1
           flash.toValue = 0.1
           flash.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
           flash.autoreverses = true
           flash.repeatCount = numberOfFlashes
           layer.add(flash, forKey: nil)
       }
 }
```

Comment: Suppose I wanted to remove the flash before the numberOfFlashes completes. Would that be, `layer.removeAllAnimations()`? Or `layer.removeAnimation(forKey:"opacity")`?

Comment: Trying both out, only the first worked. I noticed that there is no forKeyPath: option like in the way the animation was set up and using forKey: as in my comment, did not work.

Comment: There is an option of `forKeyPath:` it is not working because somehow animation with that key is not in the list. You can check active animations from layer.animationKeys()

Comment: What I'm saying is that the compiler stated there was no signature with `forKeyPath:`. I'll try again when I next have a chance. Maybe it's one of those things that restarting Xcode fixes. :)

Comment: I don't see an option to remove an animation with a `keyPath` in the documentation here. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer

Comment: This seems to be what is required. Instead of `layer.add(flash, forKey: nil)` use `layer.add(flash, forKey: "myKey")`. Then to remove the animation, don't try to find the opacity keyPath. Instead, `layer.removeAnimation(forKey:"myKey")`. BTW, active animations with nil keys are apparently not listed despite being active, so it's probably a good idea to always set a key.

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin in class function for the count and call it in the block.

`class func setAnimationRepeatCount(_ repeatCount: Float)`

```
  func startBlink() {
              UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8,//Time duration
                            delay:0.0,
                            options:[.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseInOut,    .autoreverse, .repeat],
                            animations: { 

       UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(30) // repeat 30 times.

     self.alpha = 0 
       },
                            completion: nil)
    }
```